# Fetching Ienumerable list of ids from an people and group field of a list

Tags: list, multi-select

i have a list with a field (Customers) of people and group type with multiselection set to true i want to fetch the IEnumerable list of ids from that field as that field contains value in the format somewhat like (3;#;username)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the SPFieldUserValueCollection and obtain the id value like so:

```
SPFieldUserValueCollection collection = new SPFieldUserValueCollection(web, listItem["Customers"]);
foreach (SPFieldUserValue value in collection)
{
    value = value.LookupId
}
```